# "Fairly" can't be used with comparatives or negatives

Tags: adverbs, negation, comparatives, style-manuals

> Don't use ‘**fairly**’ in front of a comparative form, **the train is
> fairly quicker than the bus*; in more formal writing, you use *rather*
> or *somewhat*.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/fairly

> FAIRLY: (not used with a negative) 1. moderately 3. absolutely
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/fairly

> We don’t use **pretty** in negative sentences: ✳*The restaurant was**n’t**
> very/so/***pretty*** good, really.*
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pretty

What is the reason for this?

Comment: It sounds weird.

Comment: The second and third are not true in specific uses in conversations: No, he wasn't fairly good. No, the restaurant is not pretty good.

Comment: @Lambie those metalinguistic uses are always possible

Comment: Not sure I would call them metalinguistic.

Comment: There are a lot of special rules and prohibitions in negative contexts[(http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf). There's a whole list of [Negative Polarity Items[(http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) like _ever_ or _in weeks_ that can only occur in negative environments -- and a whole list of environments that count as "negative", too, like comparatives and questions.

Comment: @JohnLawler Regarding comparatives, does it apply only to _ever_? See [far](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:far#Negative_Polarity_Item;_Not_attributively)  and [quite](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:quite#Not_used_with_a_negative)

Comment: The clause containing the baseline being compared with is a negative environment _He's smarter than [anyone ever thought he was]_. The rest of the comparative isn't.

Comment: This could be reopened if you edited it and added a lot more detail about what you are curious about. If all you're wondering about is wordreference, then that is short sighted and you should provide what other sources say about it (ie I don't think 'fairly' is special here - you can't say 'the train is very quicker' either. If that is not what you're asking about you need to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

- "Fairly" not used with negatives: This is because this sense of "fairly" is synonymous with "somewhat." It indicates a degree of something. "I'm fairly hot" = "I'm somewhat hot, partially hot." Negation is more absolute: if something is "not ___," it is no degree of ___. "I'm somewhat not cold, partly not cold" is bewildering. Proscription against using "pretty" for negatives would be for the same reason, since it's another synonymous usage meaning "somewhat" or "to a degree."
- Proscription against using "fairly" for comparison is mostly about convention, not because there's a rule but because language has fallen into these usages.

Comment: (Devil's advocate: Then by that logic, how can we say "I'm not very hot?" Negation plus (large) degree. Hm... I guess only if "not very" is taken as a phrase on its own, meaning "small degree.")

Comment: Apparently _Not quite_ is indeed an idiom ?https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_quite#Adverb

Comment: **quite a** ⇒ _(not used with a negative)_ "of an exceptional, considerable, or noticeable kind" https://www.wordreference.com/definition/quite

Comment: And, while "not fairly" could have been a comparable idiom had it applied itself, it isn't; see point about conventions.

Comment: There is the negation of the downtoner usage: "The restaurant wasn't _fairly good_, it was _very good indeed_!"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Right, that occurred to me. I'm not sure whether wordreference.com would frown on that as a colloquialism, but it's certainly common enough. Also, in fairness (ow), there's a difference between "was not fairly good" and "was fairly not good."

Comment: It's impeccable English, but contains a part-quote, which skews the example. << The wag didn't say that the restaurant was _fairly good_, but _fairly fairly good_. >>